# Enabling checkboxes in treeitems of ctreecntrl

Tags: windows, visual-c++, mfc, treeview, visual-c++-6

I am trying to enable/disable checkboxes in treeitems in ctreecntrl of visual c++ 6.0. I have found the options to do that for all items, but couldn't do that per item basis. Is there any function to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To turn checkboxes on and off for individual tree items, you need to send [`TVM_SETITEM` messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773758.aspx), which are used to set attributes for items in a TreeView.

The documentation says the `wParam` must be zero, and the `lParam` is a pointer to a [`TVITEM` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773456.aspx) that contains the new item attributes.

So the real battle  is in getting the `TVITEM` structure filled out accordingly. Here are the important parts:

- The `hItem` member must contain the handle to the tree item that you want to modify.
- The `mask` member should be set to `TVIF_STATE`, which indicates that the `state` and `stateMask` members are valid. Those are the ones you'll be using to turn checkboxes on and off.
- The `state` member can be set to 0, which will *hide* the checkbox for the specified tree item.
  To *show* the checkbox for the tree item, set this member of `1 << 12`. (See the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760017.aspx) for details).
- The `stateMask` member should be set to `TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK` to indicate that you're changing the item's state image index.

Since you've set `mask` to indicate that you're only using the `state` and `stateMask` members, you can happily ignore the rest of the members.

And finally, once you've got the `TVITEM` structure set, you can either use the standard `SendMessage` function, or the [`TreeView_SetItem` macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773758.aspx), to send the message to the tree item.

(Of course, the entire TreeView must have the [`TVS_CHECKBOXES` style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760013.aspx#TVS_CHECKBOXES) set in order for any of the above to work! But you said you already figured out how to do that.)